# PhpStorm - advanced settings for diff viewer

Tags: git, magento, phpstorm, diff, diffmerge

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure diff viewer in PhpStorm and specify what changes to ignore?

For example, I have updated Magento installation to a newer version.
This version contains a lot of changed files which have only one difference - the **copyright**.

[image: Copyright update diff]

I'm looking for a way to ignore such files and see the other differences.
Maybe there is a way to do this with some other tools.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible in PhpStorm -- to ignore specific lines or specific line content.

Comment: Maybe if you look in the keybinds you can find something useful? I saw some diff functions, but i don't know if they are also for diff tool or only for VCS merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried to do this in phpstorm, but if you're open to other tools, BeyondCompare (commercial, but relatively inexpensive) can do this...

http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3

To apply your changes to all of the files in a session...

With a Text Compare active, click on the 'Rules' button or go to the menu item "Session -> Session Settings..." and then select the 'Importance' tab which doesn't appear on Folder Compares (the session settings are entirely different depending on which type of compare you're doing). You can define specific text to ignore there as well as edit the grammar.

Down at the bottom of the dialog there's a select box for whether this applies to just the view you're displaying or more broadly. Select 'Use for all files within parent session', save it, make sure the File Comparison you're displaying matches the way you want, and then do a full refresh to apply that comparison to the rest of the files in the session.

If the rules are the only thing you care about switch to the Folder Comparison, click the 'Rules' button and then in the 'Comparison' tab, check 'Compare contents:Rules-based comparison' and turn on 'Override quick test results', and check 'Skip if quick tests indicate files are the same'

Comment: Thanks for the tip, going to try it today.

Comment: Amazing tool! Thanks for sharing! There are lot of different settings, figured out how to ignore changes on the file diff level, but can't find how to do this for the folders diff.

Comment: @MageLover I added some instructions to my answer